# Why is my form error not throwing back the correct message its supposed to from form validation?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im trying to input a custom form error that will throw back ab error to a user saying "You do not have an account.click here to sign up. But at the moment I see nothing in the view if I input an incorrect username that doesnt exist in my profile database. I have a lang file that loads this error that I have defined already in my autoload.php file: $autoload['language'] = array('myerrors'); Is the problem with my view? I think I need to be using a form_error line but im not exactly where...the name of the error defined is validateUser_error.

Model:

```
   function validateUser($username, $password)
     {
      $this->db->select('*')->from('membership');
      $this->db->where('username', $username);
      $this->db->where('password', $password);
      $query = $this->db->get();
      if ($query ->num_rows ==1)
     {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('validateUser_error');

        return true;
    }

    else{
        return false;

       }
    }
```

View:

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?=form_open('login/loguserin');?>
  <p>
    username <?=form_input('username');?>
  </p>
  <p>
    password <?=form_password('password');?>
  </p>
  <p>
  <?=form_submit('submit', 'Login'); ?>
  <?=form_close(); ?>
</p>
```

Controller:

function loguserin()

{

```
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[12]|callback_validateUser_error|trim');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5|trim');


$username = $this->input->post('username');
$password = $this->input->post('password');

$valid = $this->membership->validateUser($username, $password);

if ($this->form_validation->run() && $valid == true)
{
    $this->session->set_userdata('status', 'OK');
    $this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);

    redirect('home');
}
else
{
    $this->session->set_userdata('status', 'NOT_OK');
    $this->load->view('shared/header');
    $this->load->view('account/logintitle');
    $this->load->view('account/loginview');
    $this->load->view('shared/footer');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit strange to set this message in a model - the usual place to do so is a controller...

Also, if you do autoload `form_validation`, then why do you load it again in the controller? And if you don't, you should also load it in a model if you you want to set the message there.

But the main thing is that the validation message will only appear if the function `validateUser_error` returns false - this function does not seem to be present in your sample.

There are different ways to change the code, but basically your validateUser() should be called by validateUser_error() (which will be called by CI automatically because it is in validation rules) that can take the data from form fields and also unconditionally call

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('validateUser_error', 'Error message');
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change the model method so it just returns true or false. 
Make a message to display in the view if failed.

```
 if( $this->membership->validateUser($username, $password) == false ) 
 {
      $data['error_msg'] = 'OMG what is up with your fat fingers? ';
      // load view, pass $data, $error_msg will be available in yr view
      $this->load->view('account/loginview', $data);
 } 
 else
 {
      // keep going 

 }
```

Also you will have more options if check for username, then check for password.

Another way to do it is to have a separate method if it failed, and use $this->error_msg or similar. especially if you are loading a bunch of views you wont have to repeat it

```
 if( $this->membership->validateUser($username) == false ) 
  {
  $this->error_msg = 'No user by that name ';   
  $this->loginFail();
  } 
  elseif( $this->membership->validatePass($password) == false ) 
  {
  $this->error_msg = 'Password does not match this user name';   
  $this->loginFail();
  }
```

then in loginFail() you would load your views, and the appropriate error message will automatically be passed to the view:

```
 $data['error_msg'] = $this->error_msg ;
```